# Struct array indexing in C

Tags: c, arrays, enums

I want to define structure array such a way so that search operation can be performed easily and string can be retrieved using enum value.

For example:

```
enum MY_ENUM { 
    MY_ENUM_VAL = 0,
    MY_ENUM_VAL_8 = 8,
    MY_ENUM_VAL_50 = 50,
    MY_ENUM_VAL_200 = 200,
    MY_ENUM_VAL_565 = 565,
};

struct my_struct {
    int val;
    char *str;
};


/* Struct array */
struct my_struct my_struct_array[] = {
    { MY_ENUM_VAL,  "str0" },
    { MY_ENUM_VAL_8, "str8" },
    { MY_ENUM_VAL_50, "str50" },
    { MY_ENUM_VAL200, "str200" },
    { MY_ENUM_VAL_565, "str565" },
};
```

Advantage of defining array like this is that I can do search operation and also if I can't find any value in the array then I can assign some default value. But what if I want to find some string using enum value like

```
char *str50 = my_struct_array[MY_ENUM_VAL50].str; // this won't work.
```

If I index based on enum values like below then I can't do search operation. Also, if I have some random value like 300, I may get some garbage value.

```
/* String array */
const char *my_string_array[] = {
    [MY_ENUM_VAL] = "str0",
    [MY_ENUM_VAL_8] = "str8",
    [MY_ENUM_VAL_50] = "str50",
    [MY_ENUM_VAL200] = "str200",
    [MY_ENUM_VAL_565] = "str565",
};
```

What is the best/optimal way to define array so that both of above mentioned operation can be achieved?

Comment: *" But what if I want to find some string using enum value like..."* - plain and simple, you can't. That's not how your base array was defined. Of course you can stand up an array of 566 pointers, all but a handful initialized to your "default value" and the remainders set to your specific strings. You won't get better performance than direct lookup at the cost of an elaborate (and overt) storage facility and initialization setup. That said, if this is somehow the critical performance path of your code, wow.

Answer (score 0):

Quick search is not a trivial operation. C language offers no simple way to process (key, value) mappings like `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` in C++ or
`dict` in Python. You can only use functions from the standard library. C99 defines `bsearch` which allows a dichotomic search in a sorted array, and Posix defines `lsearch` (linear search) and `hsearch` (direct access with key hash). Or in plain and single C, scan the array for your key.

Comment: "C language offers no simple way to process .. map" – not the standard libraries, no, but it's always possible to write a function for it. At what array size would this outperform the simple loop? (Which, I agree, would be my initial solution until I need it to work on *huge* lists.)